# How do you find all list items between two tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For example, I'd like to pull out only Child1, Child2, and Child3 out of the below list where it is after the first instance of h3 and before the next tag of h3

```
<h3>HeaderName1<h3>
<ul class="prodoplist">
 <li>Parent</li>
 <li class="lev1">Child1</li>
 <li class="lev1">Child2</li>
 <li class="lev1">Child3</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>HeaderName2<h3>
   <ul class="prodoplist">
   <li>Parent2</li>
   <li class="lev1">Child4</li>
   <li class="lev1">Child5</li>
   <li class="lev1">Child6</li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using findChildren like:

```
for ul in soup.find_all('ul'):
    print 'ul start'
    for idx, li in enumerate(ul.findChildren('li')):
        if idx in range(3):
            print li
```

output:

```
ul start
<li>Parent</li>
<li class="lev1">Child1</li>
<li class="lev1">Child2</li>
ul start
<li>Parent2</li>
<li class="lev1">Child4</li>
<li class="lev1">Child5</li>
```

however, as in most cases [lxml and xpath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) is a superior solution:

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.parse('input.html')
print [ul.xpath('li[1] | li[2] | li[3]') for ul in doc.xpath('//ul')]
```

Comment: You can use lxml as parser for beautifulsoup4. Just use like this: `bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')`

Answer (score 2):

This should work .

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '<h3>HeaderName1</h3><ul class="prodoplist"><li>Parent</li><li class="lev1">Child1</li><li class="lev1">Child2</li><li class="lev1">Child3</li></ul>  <h3>HeaderName2</h3><ul class="prodoplist"><li>Parent2</li><li class="lev1">Child4</li><li class="lev1">Child5</li><li class="lev1">Child6</li></ul>'
m = re.search(r'<h3>.*?<h3>', html_doc, re.DOTALL)
s = m.start()
e = m.end() - len('<h3>')
target_html = html_doc[s:e]
new_bs = BeautifulSoup(target_html)
ul_eles = new_bs.findAll('ul', attrs={'class' : 'prodoplist'})
for ul_ele in ul_eles:
    li_eles = new_bs.findAll('li', attrs={'class' : 'lev1'})
    for li_ele in li_eles:
        print li_ele.text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

children = []

url = "http://someurl.html"
r = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for uls in bs.findAll('ul', 'prodoplist'):
    lis = uls.findAll('li', 'lev1')
    for li in lis:
        children.append(li.text)

print children
```